# Frage zur gewünschten Ankunftszeit formulieren

Tags: phrase, phrase-request, formality

Ich frage mich, wie man am besten die optimale Ankuftzeit / Reinkommen-Zeit erfragt.

Angenommen mich erwartet morgen ein neuer Arbeitsgeber und ich möchte ihn fragen, welche Uhrzeit seinerseits am besten passt, um mich zu empfangen, wie würde in dieser Situation eine solche Frage formulieren?

Ich habe zum Beispiel die Frage so formuliert

> Welche Uhrzeit passt Ihnen, um dort zu sein?

jedoch klingt der Teil "um dort zu sein" nicht eindeutig genug.

Comment: Hallo Mohamed, willkommen bei German.Stackexchange. Hier kannst du eine Tour machen: https://german.stackexchange.com/tour. Grußformeln und Danksagungen sind in Fragen hier unüblich, daher habe sie gelöscht. Ein Upvote ist Dank genug :). Du musst auch nicht sofort die erste Antwort annehmen, vorallem wenn sie noch wenig Upvotes hat. Oft haben Fragen hier mehrere Antworten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es hängt natürlich von der Stilebene ab: mündlich, schriftlich, privat, offiziell, förmlich, leger? Welches Verhältnis hast du mit dem Arbeitgeber? Kennt ihr euch? Seht ihr euch zum ersten Mal? Und so weiter.

Hier sind ein paar typische Sätze, die - in ihrer Stilebene - gut klingen:

(*Anmerkung: Die Antwort ist jetzt ein Community Wiki. Wer immer etwas verbessern oder ergänzen will: willkommen.*)

> Um welche Zeit soll ich kommen?
>
> Wann darf ich kommen?
>
> Wann genau soll ich kommen? (Das "genau" kannst du hinzufügen, wenn zuvor schon eine Zeit genannt wurde, z.B. "Kommen Sie morgen nachmittag." - "Gerne. Wann genau?")
>
> Zu welcher Zeit ist mein Erscheinen sinnvoll?
>
> Möchten Sie mir einen Termin vorschlagen?
>
> Würden Sie mir eine Uhrzeit nennen?
>
> Welche Uhrzeit darf ich mir notieren?
>
> Wann wünschen Sie, dass ich bei Ihnen bin?
>
> Wann möchten Sie mich genau empfangen?
>
> Welche Uhrzeit passt Ihnen? (Wie in deiner Frage)

Für die Praxis: Die Frage der Stilebene ist vielleicht sekundär. In einem E-Mail an den Arbeitgeber kannst du jeden dieser Sätze verwenden, und er wird als wohlgeformt und freundlich wahrgenommen werden.

**Zum Beispielsatz in der Frage**

> Welche Uhrzeit passt Ihnen?

ist vollkomen in Ordnung. Jedoch *Welche Uhrzeit passt Ihnen, um dort zu sein* ist stilistisch (wenn nicht sogar grammatisch) schlecht. Der Muttersprachler verbindet das "um dort zu sein" automatisch mit dem **vorausgegangen Subjekt** (Akteur), und das ist im Beispiel der mit "Ihnen" bezeichnete Arbeitgeber. Man kann zwar sagen: *Um welche Uhrzeit passt es Ihnen, dort zu sein*, aber derjenige, um dessen Dortsein es in diesem Satz geht, ist dann der mit "Ihnen" gemeinte Mensch. Da heißt, der Arbeitgeber könnte Dich fragen: "Um welche Uhrzeit passt es Ihnen, hier zu sein?" Das wäre richtig. Denn es bist ja du, der gefragt wird *und* der dort sein soll. Grammatisch richtig wäre auch "Um welche Uhrzeit passt Ihnen mein Erscheinen?", aber das klingt so bürokratisch, dass es zu dem Missverständnis kommen könnte, du machtest dich über den Arbeitgeber lustig.

Comment: @Chritian Es geht um eine schriftliche, förmliche Frage. Wir haben uns schon mal getroffen

Comment: wie finden Sie diese Formulierung: würden Sie mir sagen, zu welcher Uhrzeit mein Erscheinen morgen für Sie am optimalsten ist?

Comment: Ich finde es bräuchte eine Erläuterung welche Frage in welche Stilebene gehört. So ist die Antwort zu ungenau

Comment: @MohamedEl *optimal* ist nicht steigerbar. Ich würde daher eher sagen: *für Sie optimal ist* oder *für Sie am günstigsten ist*.

Comment: Das "genau" in den beiden ersten Vorschlägen stört mich. Eine ungefähre Zeit ist ja noch gar nicht benannt. Auch würde ich "darf ich kommen" statt "soll ich kommen" schreiben, um auszudrücken, dass ich gerne komme.

Comment: @userunknown  Hab's ein bisschen verändert nach deinen Vorschlägen. Aber es ist, hoffe ich doch, klar, dass die genaue Formulierung dann jeweils vom Kontext abhängt, v.a. von der direkt vorhergehenden Kommunikation.

Comment: @iris  Ich hatte überlegt, das hinzuzufügen. Aber die genaue Wortwahl hängt stark von der vorhergehenden Kommunikation ab (siehe Anmerkung zur Verwendung von "genau", die ich eingefügt habe). Da würde man sich den Mund fusslig erklären, und dem Leser ist mit so einem Riesenerklärriemen dann auch nicht geholfen. Aber... ich öffne diese Antwort als Community Wiki, und du kannst gerne Stilebenen-Bemerkungen einfügen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Sehr wahr. Wenn ich weiß, dass der Bewerber kein Muttersprachler ist, würde ich wenig Aufmerksamkeit auf Nuancen legen, aber eine sorgfältig gewählte Formulierung zu schätzen wissen. Im Westen, insbesondere in Großstädten und modernen Wirtschaftszweigen drückt man sich anders auf als auf dem Land, in den 50ern usw. Dazu kommen persönliche Abweichungen vom Trend. In meinem Umfeld geht es sehr unförmlich zu; man verschleiert eher Hierarchien, als sie zu betonen und gibt sich so locker, wie möglich. Zur Sicherheit würde ich aber eher zuviel als zuwenig Respekt zeigen.

Answer (score 1):

Stilfrage... Noch eine Auswahl förmlicher Möglichkeiten:

- Welche Uhrzeit würde Ihnen passen?
- Wann können wir uns treffen?
- Um wieviel Uhr würden Sie gern kommen?
- passt es in Ihren Kalender?
- Wäre Ihnen 17h recht?
- Möchten Sie eine Uhrzeit vorschlagen?

Comment: ad c) Der Frager will kommen.